# Mediaqueries don't work in Radium

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, slick, radium

I use Radium Style component to change default-style of React-Slick. I do everything like they write in tutorial and styles are changing, but media queries don't work.

```
 <Style scopeSelector='.slick-prev' rules={{
            left: '25px',
             '@media (min-width: 400px)' : {
                  left: '100px',}
}}/>
```

I tried to use `@media (min-width: 400px)` and `@media screen and (min-width: 400px)`, and nothing help.

Comment: Seems like you have forgotten to add `@Radium` decorator on your component. [See Usage of Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium#usage)

Comment: @HardikModhaI I use it.